# What is the best way to use dictionary for saved key words in NodeJS web apps?

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I have a NodeJS web application, and I have in both client and server sides all kinds of free "floating" text entries that are just hard-coded right now.
The simplest example:

```
const removeNote = (title) => {
    const notes = loadNotes();
    const updatedNotes = notes.filter(note => note.title !== title);

    if (notes.length === updatedNotes.length + 1) {
        saveNotes(updatedNotes);
        console.log(chalk.green("The not was removed!"));
    } else {
        console.log(chalk.red("Note doesn't exist!"));
    }
}
```

As you can see, the values in console.log are hard-coded.
I want to pull out the desired values from where they will be pre-saved (Dictionary?) And use them if necessary.
This is true for the client side (for example, I want THs to contain predefined values), and also for server side (like some error messages).
In addition, I want to have a function which gets the the key of the value I want - checking if it exists, and returning the value / throwing an error accordingly.

I wanted to consult you on the most correct way to do this.
I thought to create a separate JS file that would export an object (which would work in the form of the key -value in the simplest manner).
And then when I'd import that file, I can call to every saved word in the object that way:

```
dict.errorMessage
```

When dict is the name of the imported module.
The problems are:
**1.** Will I have to call a function that checks if the value exists every time? and when should I use it?
**2.** Is there any other way to call any entry, without using the .dic ..? Something like {{keyName}}
**3.**  How can I do it in the client (hbs / ejs files)? It doesn't feel like rendering to each page his specific saved dictionary values is the best way...

Hope you can advise me what is the best way to have this done :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a messages.json file to store all your messages as key-value pairs. Load and make it accessible in the whole application. Then you can access messages like `messages[key]`.

Comment: thanks, what about using the function I mentioned? @fiveelements